# Existence of $\lim_{n}\int f_{x,n} d\mu$ implies the existence of $\lim_n \int \phi(f_{x,n}) d\mu$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

Notation: $X,Y$ are locally compact Hausdorff spaces with first countability. $C_0(X)$ denotes complex-valued continuous functions on $X$ which vanish at infinity. The space is endowed with the supremum norm $\|f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X}|f(x)|.$

Let $\phi:C_0(X) \rightarrow C_0(Y)$ be a linear isomorphism and norm-increasing with $\|\phi\| < 2.$
Its adjoint is denoted as  $\phi^*:C_0(Y)^* \rightarrow C_0(X)^*.$

For any $x \in X,$ $\mu_x$ is a unit positive mass measure concentrated at $\{x\}$ only, that is, $\mu\{x \} =1$ and $\mu(X \setminus \{ x \}) = 0.$

In Cambern's paper entitled '[A Generalized Banach Stone Theorem,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035175)', he quoted the following in the the proof:

> Let $x \in X$ be any point of $X$ and let $\{ U_n:n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a neigbourhood of basis $x,$ with $U_{n+1} \subseteq U_n$ for all $n.$
>   For each $n$, choose a function $f_{x,n} \in C_0(X)$ with $f_{x,n}(x) = \| f_{x,n}\|_{\infty} = 1$ and $f_{x,n}(x^{\prime}) = 0$ for all $x^{\prime} \in X \setminus U_n.$ Then $\lim_{n}\int f_{x,n} d\mu$ exists for all $\mu \in C_0(X)^*,$ **and hence $\lim_n \int \phi(f_{x,n}) d\mu$ exists for all $\mu \in C_0(Y)^*.$**

Question: How to obtain existence of $\lim_n \int \phi(f_{x,n}) d\mu$?

I know that the existence of $\lim_{n}\int f_{x,n} d\mu$ is due to [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), as $\lim_{n}f_{x,n} = \chi_{\{x\}},$ hence   $\lim_{n}\int f_{x,n} d\mu = \mu \{ x \}.$ But I have no idea on how to obtain $\lim_n \int \phi(f_{x,n}) d\mu$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note
$$
\int \phi (f_{x,n}) d\mu = \int f_{x,n} d\phi^\ast (\mu),
$$
and apply what you already know to $\phi^\ast  (\mu) $ instead of $\mu $.